# Integrability except at finite many points.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x)=g(x)$ everywhere in $[a,b]$ except at $x_0\in [a,b]$. If $f$ is integrable, show that $g$ is also integrable.

My attempt: Let $\epsilon>0$, let $D$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,D)-L(f,D)<\epsilon$. Let $\delta$ be suitably small such that $x_{0-\delta},x_{0+\delta}$ are contained in $D$ and within $[a,b]$. Note that if they aren't in D then you can adjoin them into the set and get a new partition $D'$ such that $U(f,D')-L(f,D')<\epsilon$. Then $U(g,D)=U(f,D)$ because $supf=supg$ and $inff=inf g$ at each interval being evaluated and thus $L(g,D)=U(f,D)$. Consequently, $U(g,D)-L(g,D)<\epsilon$.

Is the proof correct?

Note $U(g,D)$ $,$ $L(g,D)$ are the upper and lower sums respectively.

Note: I have ignored the case where $x_0$ is an endpoint.

Comment: You assumed both $f,g$ are integrable to begin with

Comment: @zhw. I edited it. My mistake.

Comment: The integrability you're thinking is Riemann's?

Comment: @antonzm yup, that is correct

Comment: There's [Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann Integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability), whose proof is not too hard to follow and which is very general for dealing with these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]\setminus \{x_0\}}f(x)dx+\int_{\{x_0\}}f(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]\setminus \{x_0\}}f(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]\setminus \{x_0\}}g(x)dx=$$
$$\int_{[a,b]\setminus \{x_0\}}g(x)dx+\int_{\{x_0\}}g(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]}g(x)dx$$

Where the second inequality is just splitting the integration area into two disjoint sets, the third equality comes from the fact that the Reimann integral at a single point is zero (more generally, the Lebesgue integral with respect to an absolutely continuous measure is zero in a point), the third inequality comes from $f$ and $g$ being the same everywhere but at $x_0$, the fourth inequality comes from the same argument about integrating at a given point, and the fifth inequality comes from putting back together the sum of integrals over disjoint sets.

Therefore, as $\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]}g(x)dx$, if $f$ is integrable, $g$ is too.

Comment: what about my proof, is it incorrect?